# jQuery - turn a function with ajax call, syncronous

Tags: jquery

well, i know the title isn't the best, but i'll be as clear as possible:

I have a function that does some stuff, and then makes an ajax call with a callback; I don't want to make that ajax call syncronous. what i need is something like:

```
function theFunctionToCall(){
  //do stuff
  $.post('ajax.php',data, function(){
    //mycallback; 
  })
}

execute(theFunctionToCall, function(){
   //code to execute after the callback from theFunctionToCall is complete
})
```

is this even possible? how?

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: well, the other question / answers may have more / better quality and views, but how can my question be a duplicate if i posted it 2 years earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your functions accept an argument to pass the callback function along:

```
function theFunctionToCall(data, fn) {
    $.post('ajax.php', data, fn);
}
```

although I don't see what the particular advantage is to trying to have additional functions delegate which ajax methods are passed which callbacks.

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for. thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to make function calls run in a specified order.

```
$(document).queue('AJAX', function(next){
    $.post('ajax.php',data, function(){
        // Callback...
        next(); // Runs the next function in the queue
    });
});

$(document).queue('AJAX', function(next){
    // This will run after the POST and its callback is done
    next();  // Runs the next function, or does nothing if the queue is empty
});

$(document).dequeue('AJAX');  // Runs the 1st function in the queue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function execute(first, callbackFn) {
    first.call(null, callbackFn);
}

function theFunctionToCall(callbackFn){
    //do stuff
    $.post('ajax.php',data, callbackFn)
}

execute(theFunctionToCall, function(){
    //code to execute after the callback from theFunctionToCall is complete
})
```