# How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

How do I return the response/result from a function `foo` that makes an asynchronous request?

I am trying to return the value from the callback, as well as assigning the result to a local variable inside the function and returning that one, but none of those ways actually return the response — they all return `undefined` or whatever the initial value of the variable `result` is.

**Example of an asynchronous function that accepts a callback** (using jQuery's `ajax` function):

```
function foo() {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            result = response;
            // return response; // <- I tried that one as well
        }
    });

    return result; // It always returns `undefined`
}
```

**Example using Node.js:**

```
function foo() {
    var result;

    fs.readFile("path/to/file", function(err, data) {
        result = data;
        // return data; // <- I tried that one as well
    });

    return result; // It always returns `undefined`
}
```

**Example using the `then` block of a promise:**

```
function foo() {
    var result;

    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        result = response;
        // return response; // <- I tried that one as well
    });

    return result; // It always returns `undefined`
}
```

Comment: use deasync like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051880/2083877

Comment: @SunilKumar I don't think this is useful. OP made this question and self-answer to document how to get the response from async calls. Suggesting a 3rd party module defeats such purpose, and IMO the paradigm introduced by that module is not good practice.

Comment: @Liam: It's just an example for an asynchronous function that accepts a callback.

Comment: Promises provide a cleaner and more structured way to deal with asynchronous operations. You can create promise that represents the result of the asynchronous call. The promise can be resolved with the response or rejected with an error.

Answer (score 6625, accepted):

> *→ For a more general explanation of asynchronous behaviour with different examples, see* [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196)
>
> *→ If you already understand the problem, skip to the possible solutions below.*

## The problem

The **A** in [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) stands for [**asynchronous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asynchronous). That means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow. In your example, `$.ajax` returns immediately and the next statement, `return result;`, is executed before the function you passed as `success` callback was even called.

Here is an analogy which hopefully makes the difference between synchronous and asynchronous flow clearer:

### Synchronous

Imagine you make a phone call to a friend and ask him to look something up for you. Although it might take a while, you wait on the phone and stare into space, until your friend gives you the answer that you needed.

The same is happening when you make a function call containing "normal" code:

```
function findItem() {
    var item;
    while(item_not_found) {
        // search
    }
    return item;
}

var item = findItem();

// Do something with item
doSomethingElse();
```

Even though `findItem` might take a long time to execute, any code coming after `var item = findItem();` has to *wait* until the function returns the result.

### Asynchronous

You call your friend again for the same reason. But this time you tell him that you are in a hurry and he should *call you back* on your mobile phone. You hang up, leave the house, and do whatever you planned to do. Once your friend calls you back, you are dealing with the information he gave to you.

That's exactly what's happening when you do an Ajax request.

```
findItem(function(item) {
    // Do something with the item
});
doSomethingElse();
```

Instead of waiting for the response, the execution continues immediately and the statement after the Ajax call is executed. To get the response eventually, you provide a function to be called once the response was received, a *callback* (notice something? *call back* ?). Any statement coming after that call is executed before the callback is called.

---

## Solution(s)

**Embrace the asynchronous nature of JavaScript!** While certain asynchronous operations provide synchronous counterparts (so does "Ajax"), it's generally discouraged to use them, especially in a browser context.

Why is it bad do you ask?

JavaScript runs in the UI thread of the browser and any long-running process will lock the UI, making it unresponsive. Additionally, there is an upper limit on the execution time for JavaScript and the browser will ask the user whether to continue the execution or not.

All of this results in a really bad user experience. The user won't be able to tell whether everything is working fine or not. Furthermore, the effect will be worse for users with a slow connection.

In the following we will look at three different solutions that are all building on top of each other:

- **Promises with `async/await`** (ES2017+, available in older browsers if you use a transpiler or regenerator)
- **Callbacks** (popular in node)
- **Promises with `then()`** (ES2015+, available in older browsers if you use one of the many promise libraries)

**All three are available in current browsers, and node 7+.**

---

### ES2017+: Promises with [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

The ECMAScript version released in 2017 introduced *syntax-level support* for asynchronous functions. With the help of `async` and `await`, you can write asynchronous in a "synchronous style". The code is still asynchronous, but it's easier to read/understand.

`async/await` builds on top of promises: an `async` function always returns a promise. `await` "unwraps" a promise and either result in the value the promise was resolved with or throws an error if the promise was rejected.

**Important:** You can only use `await` inside an `async` function or in a [JavaScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Top-level `await` is not supported outside of modules, so you might have to make an async IIFE ([Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)) to start an `async` context if not using a module.

You can read more about [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) on MDN.

Here is an example that elaborates the *delay* function `findItem()` above:

```
// Using 'superagent' which will return a promise.
var superagent = require('superagent')

// This is isn't declared as `async` because it already returns a promise
function delay() {
  // `delay` returns a promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Only `delay` is able to resolve or reject the promise
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(42); // After 3 seconds, resolve the promise with value 42
    }, 3000);
  });
}

async function getAllBooks() {
  try {
    // GET a list of book IDs of the current user
    var bookIDs = await superagent.get('/user/books');
    // wait for 3 seconds (just for the sake of this example)
    await delay();
    // GET information about each book
    return superagent.get('/books/ids='+JSON.stringify(bookIDs));
  } catch(error) {
    // If any of the awaited promises was rejected, this catch block
    // would catch the rejection reason
    return null;
  }
}

// Start an IIFE to use `await` at the top level
(async function(){
  let books = await getAllBooks();
  console.log(books);
})();
```

Current [browser](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-async_functions) and [node](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) versions support `async/await`. You can also support older environments by transforming your code to ES5 with the help of [regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator) (or tools that use regenerator, such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

---

### Let functions accept *callbacks*

A callback is when function 1 is passed to function 2. Function 2 can call function 1 whenever it is ready. In the context of an asynchronous process, the callback will be called whenever the asynchronous process is done. Usually, the result is passed to the callback.

In the example of the question, you can make `foo` accept a callback and use it as `success` callback. So this

```
var result = foo();
// Code that depends on 'result'
```

becomes

```
foo(function(result) {
    // Code that depends on 'result'
});
```

Here we defined the function "inline" but you can pass any function reference:

```
function myCallback(result) {
    // Code that depends on 'result'
}

foo(myCallback);
```

`foo` itself is defined as follows:

```
function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: callback
    });
}
```

`callback` will refer to the function we pass to `foo` when we call it and we pass it on to `success`. I.e. once the Ajax request is successful, `$.ajax` will call `callback` and pass the response to the callback (which can be referred to with `result`, since this is how we defined the callback).

You can also process the response before passing it to the callback:

```
function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(response) {
            // For example, filter the response
            callback(filtered_response);
        }
    });
}
```

It's easier to write code using callbacks than it may seem. After all, JavaScript in the browser is heavily event-driven (DOM events). Receiving the Ajax response is nothing else but an event.
Difficulties could arise when you have to work with third-party code, but most problems can be solved by just thinking through the application flow.

---

### ES2015+: Promises with [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a new feature of ECMAScript 6 (ES2015), but it has good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) already. There are also many libraries which implement the standard Promises API and provide additional methods to ease the use and composition of asynchronous functions (e.g., [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)).

Promises are containers for *future* values. When the promise receives the value (it is *resolved*) or when it is canceled (*rejected*), it notifies all of its "listeners" who want to access this value.

The advantage over plain callbacks is that they allow you to decouple your code and they are easier to compose.

Here is an example of using a promise:

```js
function delay() {
  // `delay` returns a promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Only `delay` is able to resolve or reject the promise
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(42); // After 3 seconds, resolve the promise with value 42
    }, 3000);
  });
}

delay()
  .then(function(v) { // `delay` returns a promise
    console.log(v); // Log the value once it is resolved
  })
  .catch(function(v) {
    // Or do something else if it is rejected
    // (it would not happen in this example, since `reject` is not called).
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Applied to our Ajax call we could use promises like this:

```js
function ajax(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // Code depending on result
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // An error occurred
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Describing all the advantages that promise offer is beyond the scope of this answer, but if you write new code, you should seriously consider them. They provide a great abstraction and separation of your code.

More information about promises: [HTML5 rocks - JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

#### Side note: jQuery's deferred objects

[Deferred objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866721/what-are-deferred-objects) are jQuery's custom implementation of promises (before the Promise API was standardized). They behave almost like promises but expose a slightly different API.

Every Ajax method of jQuery already returns a "deferred object" (actually a promise of a deferred object) which you can just return from your function:

```
function ajax() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

ajax().done(function(result) {
    // Code depending on result
}).fail(function() {
    // An error occurred
});
```

#### Side note: Promise gotchas

Keep in mind that promises and deferred objects are just *containers* for a future value, they are not the value itself. For example, suppose you had the following:

```
function checkPassword() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/password',
        data: {
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

if (checkPassword()) {
    // Tell the user they're logged in
}
```

This code misunderstands the above asynchronous issues. Specifically, `$.ajax()` doesn't freeze the code while it checks the '/password' page on your server - it sends a request to the server and while it waits, it immediately returns a jQuery Ajax Deferred object, not the response from the server. That means the `if` statement is going to always get this Deferred object, treat it as `true`, and proceed as though the user is logged in. Not good.

But the fix is easy:

```
checkPassword()
.done(function(r) {
    if (r) {
        // Tell the user they're logged in
    } else {
        // Tell the user their password was bad
    }
})
.fail(function(x) {
    // Tell the user something bad happened
});
```

---

### Not recommended: Synchronous "Ajax" calls

As I mentioned, some(!) asynchronous operations have synchronous counterparts. I don't advocate their use, but for completeness' sake, here is how you would perform a synchronous call:

#### Without jQuery

If you directly use a [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) object, pass `false` as third argument to [`.open`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method).

#### jQuery

If you use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can set the `async` option to `false`. Note that this option is *deprecated* since jQuery 1.8.
You can then either still use a `success` callback or access the `responseText` property of the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

```
function foo() {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        //...
        async: false
    });
    return jqXHR.responseText;
}
```

If you use any other jQuery Ajax method, such as `$.get`, `$.getJSON`, etc., you have to change it to `$.ajax` (since you can only pass configuration parameters to `$.ajax`).

**Heads up!** It is not possible to make a synchronous [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp) request. JSONP by its very nature is always asynchronous (one more reason to not even consider this option).

Comment: @Pommy: If you want to use jQuery, you have to include it. Please refer to http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: In Solution 1, sub jQuery, I could not understand this line: `If you use any other jQuery AJAX method, such as $.get, $.getJSON, etc., you have them to $.ajax.` (Yes, I realize my nick is a tad ironic in this case)

Comment: @gibberish: Mmmh, I don't know how it can be made clearer. Do you see how `foo` is called and a function is passed to it (`foo(function(result) {....});`)? `result` is used inside this function and is the response of the Ajax request. To refer to this function, the first parameter of foo is called `callback` and assigned to `success` instead of an anonymous function. So, `$.ajax` will call `callback` when the request was successful. I tried to explain it a bit more.

Comment: The Chat for this question is dead so I'm not sure where to propose outlined changes, but I propose: 1) Change the synchronous part to a simple discussion of why it's bad with no code example of how to do it. 2) Remove/merge the callback examples to only show the more flexible Deferred approach, which I think may also be a little easier to follow for those learning Javascript.

Comment: @Jessi: I think you misunderstood that part of the answer. You cannot use `$.getJSON` if you want the Ajax request to be synchronous. However, you should not event want the request to be synchronous, so that doesn't apply. You should be using callbacks or promises  to handle the response, as it is explained earlier in the answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I strongly disagree with your recent edit (the large TL;DR: Use Promises). This question is a dup target for a *large* number of general async-issue questions (how to return a variable). Putting that code/info at the start is confusing to the people who we are telling this is a duplicate of their problem. The code you provided only shows how to use the Promise that is auto-returned by jQuery's `$.ajax()` when you don't provide a callback. You have changed a general purpose answer into one which is now only specific to `$.ajax()`, or functions which auto-return a Promise.(cont)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha:(cont) This is now seen by newbies as too specific and not applicable to their question (which could be for any async function, not just `$.ajax()`). `$.ajax()` is just used as an example of the more general issue. Note that I am only here at this question/answer now because what I describe as the response newbies is what has happened when I suggested this as a dup target on a question. If you were not a moderator, I would just revert the edit while we discuss it, but I don't want to, potentially, get into a rollback contest with a moderator.

Comment: So I must wrap the main function in an async function and then use await in order to get a value from an async function, right?

Comment: @Kadio: Not necessarily. An async function returns a promise, so you can also pass a callback to the promise's `then` method: `asyncFunction().then(result => ...)`.

Comment: `return await` is a mistake and should **always** be avoided

Comment: The only thing I can see is: JavaScript is an enemy to clean code/architecture. As soon as you need to call anything returning a promise, bid farewell to any separation of concerns in your code: any such module or code will need to end up in a callback hell which ends up outputting data (whatever would be the now-toilet-flushed objective of the module or class, it will now obey the Single-Responsibility-Plus-Output Principle).

Comment: This answer has lots of great information, but I don't think it has a solution to my problem. I'm using the jQuery validator plugin. The plugin has you call its addMethod() function to define a function that it will call on an input element whose name attribute you specify. The function you define must return true or false. But I need to use $.ajax to check with the server if a value is valid. So I need the method called by the validator to return the result of the $.ajax call.  I don't have the option of passing in a function to my validator to be called on ajax completion. (cont'd)

Comment: The only solution I could come up with was to use the async: false option to $.ajax. And I have been roundly scolded for doing that because it is an anti-pattern, and referred to this post. But I cannot find a different solution in this post!

Comment: I asked a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215159/jquery-validation-plugin-validation-custom-method-needs-to-return-result-of-aj) about the jQuery validator plugin, which got an excellent answer. Basically, the interface for custom validation methods for that plugin requires that the method it calls return a boolean, and therefore the method cannot use ajax unless it specifies `async: false`. In order to avoid making a synchronous call, you must use the plugin's builtin `remote` method. That method can internally make an async call, because the result is (cont'd)

Comment: only used to make changes to the DOM, it doesn't need to set a value to be returned from the function making the ajax request.

Answer (score 1224):

## If you're *not* using jQuery in your code, this answer is for you

Your code should be something along the lines of this:

```
function foo() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "/echo/json");
    httpRequest.send();
    return httpRequest.responseText;
}

var result = foo(); // Always ends up being 'undefined'
```

[Felix Kling did a fine job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) writing an answer for people using jQuery for AJAX, but I've decided to provide an alternative for people who aren't.

([Note, for those using the new `fetch` API, Angular or promises I've added another answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/1348195))

---

## What you're facing

This is a short summary of "Explanation of the problem" from the other answer, if you're not sure after reading this, read that.

The **A** in AJAX stands for **asynchronous**. That means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow. In your example, [`.send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) returns immediately and the next statement, `return result;`, is executed before the function you passed as `success` callback was even called.

This means when you're returning, the listener you've defined did not execute yet, which means the value you're returning has not been defined.

Here is a simple analogy:

```
function getFive(){
    var a;
    setTimeout(function(){
         a=5;
    },10);
    return a;
}
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7RK3k/)

The value of `a` returned is `undefined` since the `a=5` part has not executed yet. AJAX acts like this, you're returning the value before the server got the chance to tell your browser what that value is.

One possible solution to this problem is to code *re-actively* , telling your program what to do when the calculation completed.

```
function onComplete(a){ // When the code completes, do this
    alert(a);
}

function getFive(whenDone){
    var a;
    setTimeout(function(){
         a=5;
         whenDone(a);
    },10);
}
```

This is called [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Basically, we're passing `getFive` an action to perform when it completes, we're telling our code how to react when an event completes (like our AJAX call, or in this case the timeout).

Usage would be:

```
getFive(onComplete);
```

Which should alert "5" to the screen. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/PAjZR/).

## Possible solutions

There are basically two ways how to solve this:

1. Make the AJAX call synchronous (let’s call it SJAX).
2. Restructure your code to work properly with callbacks.

### 1. Synchronous AJAX - Don't do it!!

As for synchronous AJAX, **don't do it!** Felix's answer raises some compelling arguments about why it's a bad idea. To sum it up, it'll freeze the user's browser until the server returns the response and create a very bad user experience. Here is another short summary taken from MDN on why:

> XMLHttpRequest supports both synchronous and asynchronous communications. In general, however, asynchronous requests should be preferred to synchronous requests for performance reasons.
>
> In short, synchronous requests block the execution of code... ...this can cause serious issues...

If you *have* to do it, you can pass a flag. [Here is how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'yourURL', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {// That's HTTP for 'ok'
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

### 2. Restructure code

Let your function accept a callback. In the example code `foo` can be made to accept a callback. We'll be telling our code how to *react* when `foo` completes.

So:

```
var result = foo();
// Code that depends on `result` goes here
```

Becomes:

```
foo(function(result) {
    // Code that depends on `result`
});
```

Here we passed an anonymous function, but we could just as easily pass a reference to an existing function, making it look like:

```
function myHandler(result) {
    // Code that depends on `result`
}
foo(myHandler);
```

For more details on how this sort of callback design is done, check Felix's answer.

Now, let's define foo itself to act accordingly

```
function foo(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onload = function(){ // When the request is loaded
       callback(httpRequest.responseText);// We're calling our method
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', "/echo/json");
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DAcWT/)

We have now made our *foo* function accept an action to run when the AJAX completes successfully. We can extend this further by checking if the response status is not 200 and acting accordingly (create a fail handler and such). Effectively it is solving our issue.

If you're still having a hard time understanding this, [read the AJAX getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) at MDN.

Comment: "synchronous requests block the execution of code and can leak memory and events" how can a synchronous request leak memory?

Answer (score 454):

**[XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) 2** (first of all, read the answers from [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/19068) and [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/19068))

If you don't use jQuery and want a nice short XMLHttpRequest 2 which works in modern browsers and also in mobile browsers, I suggest using it this way:

```
function ajax(a, b, c){ // URL, callback, just a placeholder
  c = new XMLHttpRequest;
  c.open('GET', a);
  c.onload = b;
  c.send()
}
```

As you can see:

1. It's shorter than all other functions Listed.
2. The callback is set directly (so no extra unnecessary closures).
3. It uses the new onload (so you don't have to check for readystate && status)
4. There are some other situations, which I don't remember, that make the XMLHttpRequest 1 annoying.

There are two ways to get the response of this Ajax call (three using the XMLHttpRequest var name):

The simplest:

```
this.response
```

Or if for some reason you `bind()` the callback to a class:

```
e.target.response
```

Example:

```
function callback(e){
  console.log(this.response);
}
ajax('URL', callback);
```

Or (the above one is better anonymous functions are always a problem):

```
ajax('URL', function(e){console.log(this.response)});
```

Nothing easier.

Now some people will probably say that it's better to use onreadystatechange or even the XMLHttpRequest variable name. That's wrong.

Check out [XMLHttpRequest advanced features](http://caniuse.com/xhr2).

It supported all *modern browsers. And I can confirm as I have been using this approach since XMLHttpRequest 2 was created. I never had any type of problem in any browsers I used.

onreadystatechange is only useful if you want to get the headers on state 2.

Using the `XMLHttpRequest` variable name is another big error as you need to execute the callback inside the onload/oreadystatechange closures, or else you lost it.

---

Now if you want something more complex using [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and FormData you can easily extend this function:

```
function x(a, b, e, d, c){ // URL, callback, method, formdata or {key:val},placeholder
  c = new XMLHttpRequest;
  c.open(e||'get', a);
  c.onload = b;
  c.send(d||null)
}
```

Again ... it's a very short function, but it does [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and POST.

Examples of usage:

```
x(url, callback); // By default it's GET so no need to set
x(url, callback, 'post', {'key': 'val'}); // No need to set POST data
```

Or pass a full form element (`document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]`):

```
var fd = new FormData(form);
x(url, callback, 'post', fd);
```

Or set some custom values:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('key', 'val')
x(url, callback, 'post', fd);
```

As you can see, I didn't implement sync... it's a bad thing.

Having said that ... why don't we do it the easy way?

---

As mentioned in the comment, the use of error && synchronous does completely break the point of the answer. Which is a nice short way to use Ajax properly?

*Error handler*

```
function x(a, b, e, d, c){ // URL, callback, method, formdata or {key:val}, placeholder
  c = new XMLHttpRequest;
  c.open(e||'get', a);
  c.onload = b;
  c.onerror = error;
  c.send(d||null)
}

function error(e){
  console.log('--Error--', this.type);
  console.log('this: ', this);
  console.log('Event: ', e)
}
function displayAjax(e){
  console.log(e, this);
}
x('WRONGURL', displayAjax);
```

In the above script, you have an error handler which is statically defined, so it does not compromise the function. The error handler can be used for other functions too.

But to get out an error, the **only** way is to write a wrong URL in which case every browser throws an error.

Error handlers may maybe useful if you set custom headers, set the responseType to blob array buffer, or whatever...

Even if you pass 'POSTAPAPAP' as the method it won't throw an error.

Even if you pass 'fdggdgilfdghfldj' as formdata it won't throw an error.

In the first case, the error is inside the `displayAjax()` under `this.statusText` as `Method not Allowed`.

In the second case, it simply works. You have to check on the server side if you passed the right post data.

Cross-domain not allowed throws an error automatically.

In the error response, there aren't any error codes.

There is only the `this.type` which is set to *error*.

Why add an error handler if you don't have any control over errors?
Most of the errors are returned inside this in the callback function `displayAjax()`.

So: There isn't any need for error checks if you're able to copy and paste the URL properly. ;)

*PS: As the first test I wrote x('x', displayAjax)..., and it totally got a response...??? So I checked the folder where the HTML is located, and there was a file called 'x.xml'. So even if you forget the extension of your file XMLHttpRequest 2 WILL FIND IT*. I LOL'd

---

*Read a file synchronous*

**Don't do that.**

If you want to block the browser for a while load a nice big `.txt` file synchronous.

```
function omg(a, c){ // URL
  c = new XMLHttpRequest;
  c.open('GET', a, true);
  c.send();
  return c; // Or c.response
}
```

Now you can do

```
 var res = omg('thisIsGonnaBlockThePage.txt');
```

There is no other way to do this in a non-asynchronous way. (Yeah, with setTimeout loop... but seriously?)

Another point is... if you work with APIs or just your own list's files or whatever you always use different functions for each request...

Only if you have a page where you load always the same XML/JSON or whatever you need only one function. In that case, modify a little the Ajax function and replace b with your special function.

---

The functions above are for basic use.

If you want to *extend* the function...

Yes, you can.

I'm using a lot of APIs and one of the first functions I integrate into every HTML page is the first Ajax function in this answer, with GET only...

But you can do a lot of stuff with XMLHttpRequest 2:

I made a download manager (using ranges on both sides with resume, filereader, and filesystem), various image resizers converters using canvas, populate web SQL databases with base64images and much more...

But in these cases you should create a function only for that purpose... sometimes you need a blob, or array buffers, you can set headers, override mimetype and there is a lot more...

But the question here is how to return an Ajax response... (I added an easy way.)

Comment: While this answer is nice (And we all _love_ XHR2 and posting file data and multipart data is totally awesome) - this shows syntactic sugar for posting XHR with JavaScript - you might want to put this in a blog post (I'd like it) or even in a library (not sure about the name `x`, `ajax` or `xhr` might be nicer :)). I don't see how it addresses returning the response from an AJAX call. (someone could still do `var res = x("url")` and not understand why it doesn't work ;)). On a side note - it would be cool if you returned `c` from the method so users can hook on `error` etc.

Comment: `2.ajax is meant to be async.. so NO var res=x('url')..` That's the entire point of this question and answers :)

Comment: @cocco So you wrote misleading, unreadable code in a SO _answer_ in order to save a few keystrokes? Please don't do that.

Answer (score 376):

### If you're using promises, this answer is for you.

This means AngularJS, jQuery (with deferred), native [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)'s replacement (fetch), [Ember.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ember.js), [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js)'s save or any [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) library that returns promises.

Your code should be something along the lines of this:

```
function foo() {
    var data;
    // Or $.get(...).then, or request(...).then, or query(...).then
    fetch("/echo/json").then(function(response){
        data = response.json();
    });
    return data;
}

var result = foo(); // 'result' is always undefined no matter what.
```

[Felix Kling did a fine job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) writing an answer for people using jQuery with callbacks for Ajax. I have an answer for native XHR. This answer is for generic usage of promises either on the frontend or backend.

---

### The core issue

The JavaScript concurrency model in the browser and on the server with Node.js/io.js is *asynchronous* and *reactive*.

Whenever you call a method that returns a promise, the `then` handlers are *always* executed asynchronously - that is, **after** the code below them that is not in a `.then` handler.

This means when you're returning `data` the `then` handler you've defined did not execute yet. This in turn means that the value you're returning has not been set to the correct value in time.

Here is a simple analogy for the issue:

```js
    function getFive(){
        var data;
        setTimeout(function(){ // Set a timer for one second in the future
           data = 5; // After a second, do this
        }, 1000);
        return data;
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = getFive(); // `undefined` here and not 5
```

The value of `data` is `undefined` since the `data = 5` part has not executed yet. It will likely execute in a second, but by that time it is irrelevant to the returned value.

Since the operation did not happen yet (Ajax, server call, I/O, and timer) you're returning the value before the request got the chance to tell your code what that value is.

One possible solution to this problem is to code *re-actively*, telling your program what to do when the calculation completed. Promises actively enable this by being temporal (time-sensitive) in nature.

#### Quick recap on promises

A Promise is a *value over time*. Promises have state. They start as pending with no value and can settle to:

- **fulfilled** meaning that the computation completed successfully.
- **rejected** meaning that the computation failed.

A promise can only change states *once* after which it will always stay at the same state forever. You can attach `then` handlers to promises to extract their value and handle errors. `then` handlers allow [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks) of calls. Promises are created by [using APIs that return them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). For example, the more modern Ajax replacement `fetch` or jQuery's `$.get` return promises.

When we call `.then` on a promise and *return* something from it - we get a promise for *the processed value*. If we return another promise we'll get amazing things, but let's hold our horses.

#### With promises

Let's see how we can solve the above issue with promises. First, let's demonstrate our understanding of promise states from above by using the [Promise constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise) for creating a delay function:

```
function delay(ms){ // Takes amount of milliseconds
    // Returns a new promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){ // When the time is up,
            resolve(); // change the promise to the fulfilled state
        }, ms);
    });
}
```

Now, after we [converted setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) to use promises, we can use `then` to make it count:

```js
function delay(ms){ // Takes amount of milliseconds
  // Returns a new promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){ // When the time is up,
      resolve(); // change the promise to the fulfilled state
    }, ms);
  });
}

function getFive(){
  // We're RETURNING the promise. Remember, a promise is a wrapper over our value
  return delay(100).then(function(){ // When the promise is ready,
      return 5; // return the value 5. Promises are all about return values
  })
}
// We _have_ to wrap it like this in the call site, and we can't access the plain value
getFive().then(function(five){
   document.body.innerHTML = five;
});
```

Basically, instead of returning a *value* which we can't do because of the concurrency model - we're returning a *wrapper* for a value that we can *unwrap* with `then`. It's like a box you can open with `then`.

#### Applying this

This stands the same for your original API call, you can:

```
function foo() {
    // RETURN the promise
    return fetch("/echo/json").then(function(response){
        return response.json(); // Process it inside the `then`
    });
}

foo().then(function(response){
    // Access the value inside the `then`
})
```

So this works just as well. We've learned we can't return values from already asynchronous calls, but we can use promises and chain them to perform processing. We now know how to return the response from an asynchronous call.

### ES2015 (ES6)

ES6 introduces [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) which are functions that can return in the middle and then resume the point they were at. This is typically useful for sequences, for example:

```
function* foo(){ // Notice the star. This is ES6, so new browsers, Nodes.js, and io.js only
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    while(true) yield 3;
}
```

Is a function that returns an *iterator* over the sequence `1,2,3,3,3,3,....` which can be iterated. While this is interesting on its own and opens room for a lot of possibility, there is one particular interesting case.

If the sequence we're producing is a sequence of actions rather than numbers - we can pause the function whenever an action is yielded and wait for it before we resume the function. So instead of a sequence of numbers, we need a sequence of *future* values - that is: promises.

This somewhat a tricky, but very powerful trick let’s us write asynchronous code in a synchronous manner. There are several "runners" that do this for you. Writing one is a short few lines of code, but it is beyond the scope of this answer. I'll be using Bluebird's `Promise.coroutine` here, but there are other wrappers like `co` or `Q.async`.

```
var foo = coroutine(function*(){
    var data = yield fetch("/echo/json"); // Notice the yield
    // The code here only executes _after_ the request is done
    return data.json(); // 'data' is defined
});
```

This method returns a promise itself, which we can consume from other coroutines. For example:

```
var main = coroutine(function*(){
   var bar = yield foo(); // Wait our earlier coroutine. It returns a promise
   // The server call is done here, and the code below executes when done
   var baz = yield fetch("/api/users/" + bar.userid); // Depends on foo's result
   console.log(baz); // Runs after both requests are done
});
main();
```

### ES2016 (ES7)

In ES7, this is further standardized. There are several proposals right now, but in all of them you can `await` promise. This is just "sugar" (nicer syntax) for the ES6 proposal above by adding the `async` and `await` keywords. Making the above example:

```
async function foo(){
    var data = await fetch("/echo/json"); // Notice the await
    // code here only executes _after_ the request is done
    return data.json(); // 'data' is defined
}
```

It still returns a promise just the same :)

Comment: In short, async functions can either: 1) assign meaningless 'pending' promises or 'undefined' variables to synchronous flow (common gotchas) 2) extract the response body from the fulfilled promise for their own or callback processing 3) return the promise up the 'chain' to another calling async function

Answer (score 289):

You are using Ajax incorrectly. The idea is not to have it return anything, but instead hand off the data to something called a callback function, which handles the data.

That is:

```
function handleData( responseData ) {

    // Do what you want with the data
    console.log(responseData);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "hi.php",
    ...
    success: function ( data, status, XHR ) {
        handleData(data);
    }
});
```

Returning anything in the submit handler will not do anything. You must instead either hand off the data, or do what you want with it directly inside the success function.

Comment: This answer is completely semantic... your success method is just a callback within a callback. You could just have `success: handleData` and it would work.

Answer (score 283):

I will answer with a horrible-looking, hand-drawn comic. The second image is the reason why `result` is `undefined` in your code example.

[image]

Comment: **A picture is worth a thousand words**,   **Person A** - Ask's person B  details to fix his car, in turn **Person B** - Makes Ajax Call and waits for response from server for car fixing details, when response is received, Ajax Success function  calls the Person B function and passes the response as argument to it, Person A receives the answer.

Comment: Would be great if you added lines of code with each image to illustrate the concepts.

Comment: Meanwhile, the guy with the car is stuck on the side of the road.  He *requires* the car is fixed before continuing.  He is now alone on the side of the road waiting...  He would rather be on the phone waiting for status changes but the mechanic would not do it...  The mechanic said he has to get on with his job and can't simply hang out on the phone.  Mechanic promised he would call him back as soon as he could.  After about 4 hours, the guy gives up and calls Uber.  - Example of timeout.

Comment: But with callback functions, I feel like the person on the left in the last frame is being forced *not* to give the other person their phone number. Instead they have to tell the other person, "Here's everything I want to do with the information from the dude on the phone. Do all that stuff and never tell me." What am I missing?

Comment: @FingLixon It's not a perfect comic by any stretch :-D. The 2nd image should illustrate what happens when you try to read a value too early (before a callback has occurred). The 3rd image illustrates setting up a callback method: The guy on the left basically IS the callback handler: He will be called with the information once it's available and can then do with it whatever he wants. I now think it was a bad idea to have TWO phone calls in this comic: The call to the shop and the call to the guy on the left. I should have simplified that, sorry about that.

Answer (score 265):

The simplest solution is to create a JavaScript function and call it for the Ajax `success` callback.

```
function callServerAsync(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {

            successCallback(response);
        }
    });
}

function successCallback(responseObj){
    // Do something like read the response and show data
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj)); // Only applicable to a JSON response
}

function foo(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
           return callback(null, response);
        }
    });
}

var result = foo(function(err, result){
          if (!err)
           console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I don't know who voted it negative. But this is a work around which has worked in fact i used this approach to create a whole application.  The jquery.ajax don't return data so its better to use the above approach. If it's wrong then please explain and suggest better way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to leave a comment (I usually do!). I downvoted it. Downvotes don't indicate factual correctness or lack of, they indicate usefulness in the context or lack of. I don't find your answer useful given Felix's which already explains this only in much more detail. On a side note, why would you stringify the response if it's JSON?

Comment: ok.. @Benjamin i used stringify, to convert a JSON Object to string. And thanks for clarifying your point. Will keep in mind to post more elaborate answers.

Answer (score 185):

Most of the answers here give useful suggestions for when you have a single async operation, but sometimes, this comes up when you need to do an asynchronous operation for *each* entry in an array or other list-like structure. The temptation is to do this:

```
// WRONG
var results = [];
theArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
        results.push(result);
    });
});
console.log(results); // E.g., using them, returning them, etc.
```

Example:

```js
// WRONG
var theArray = [1, 2, 3];
var results = [];
theArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
        results.push(result);
    });
});
console.log("Results:", results); // E.g., using them, returning them, etc.

function doSomethingAsync(value, callback) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
        callback(value * 2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The reason that doesn't work is that the callbacks from `doSomethingAsync` haven't run yet by the time you're trying to use the results.

So, if you have an array (or list of some kind) and want to do async operations for each entry, you have two options: Do the operations in parallel (overlapping), or in series (one after another in sequence).

#### Parallel

You can start all of them and keep track of how many callbacks you're expecting, and then use the results when you've gotten that many callbacks:

```
var results = [];
var expecting = theArray.length;
theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
        results[index] = result;
        if (--expecting === 0) {
            // Done!
            console.log("Results:", results); // E.g., using the results
        }
    });
});
```

Example:

```js
var theArray = [1, 2, 3];
var results = [];
var expecting = theArray.length;
theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
        results[index] = result;
        if (--expecting === 0) {
            // Done!
            console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results)); // E.g., using the results
        }
    });
});

function doSomethingAsync(value, callback) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
        callback(value * 2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

*(We could do away with `expecting` and just use `results.length === theArray.length`, but that leaves us open to the possibility that `theArray` is changed while the calls are outstanding...)*

Notice how we use the `index` from `forEach` to save the result in `results` in the same position as the entry it relates to, even if the results arrive out of order (since async calls don't necessarily complete in the order in which they were started).

But what if you need to *return* those results from a function? As the other answers have pointed out, you can't; you have to have your function accept and call a callback (or return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)). Here's a callback version:

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var expecting = theArray.length;
    theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
            results[index] = result;
            if (--expecting === 0) {
                // Done!
                callback(results);
            }
        });
    });
}
doSomethingWith(theArray, function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var expecting = theArray.length;
    theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
            results[index] = result;
            if (--expecting === 0) {
                // Done!
                callback(results);
            }
        });
    });
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3], function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value, callback) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
        callback(value * 2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Or here's a version returning a `Promise` instead:

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var results = [];
        var expecting = theArray.length;
        theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
            doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
                results[index] = result;
                if (--expecting === 0) {
                    // Done!
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

*Of course, if `doSomethingAsync` passed us errors, we'd use `reject` to reject the promise when we got an error.)*

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var results = [];
        var expecting = theArray.length;
        theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
            doSomethingAsync(entry, function(result) {
                results[index] = result;
                if (--expecting === 0) {
                    // Done!
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3]).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value, callback) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
        callback(value * 2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

*(Or alternately, you could make a wrapper for `doSomethingAsync` that returns a promise, and then do the below...)*

If `doSomethingAsync` gives you a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return Promise.all(theArray.map(function(entry) {
        return doSomethingAsync(entry);
    }));
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

If you know that `doSomethingAsync` will ignore a second and third argument, you can just pass it directly to `map` (`map` calls its callback with three arguments, but most people only use the first most of the time):

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return Promise.all(theArray.map(doSomethingAsync));
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return Promise.all(theArray.map(doSomethingAsync));
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3]).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
            resolve(value * 2);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Note that `Promise.all` resolves its promise with an array of the results of all of the promises you give it when they are all resolved, or rejects its promise when the *first* of the promises you give it rejects.

#### Series

Suppose you don't want the operations to be in parallel? If you want to run them one after another, you need to wait for each operation to complete before you start the next. Here's an example of a function that does that and calls a callback with the result:

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray, callback) {
    var results = [];
    doOne(0);
    function doOne(index) {
        if (index < theArray.length) {
            doSomethingAsync(theArray[index], function(result) {
                results.push(result);
                doOne(index + 1);
            });
        } else {
            // Done!
            callback(results);
        }
    }
}
doSomethingWith(theArray, function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

*(Since we're doing the work in series, we can just use `results.push(result)` since we know we won't get results out of order. In the above we could have used `results[index] = result;`, but in some of the following examples we don't have an index to use.)*

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray, callback) {
    var results = [];
    doOne(0);
    function doOne(index) {
        if (index < theArray.length) {
            doSomethingAsync(theArray[index], function(result) {
                results.push(result);
                doOne(index + 1);
            });
        } else {
            // Done!
            callback(results);
        }
    }
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3], function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value, callback) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
        callback(value * 2);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

*(Or, again, build a wrapper for `doSomethingAsync` that gives you a promise and do the below...)*

If `doSomethingAsync` gives you a Promise, if you can use ES2017+ syntax (perhaps with a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io)), you can use an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
async function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    const results = [];
    for (const entry of theArray) {
        results.push(await doSomethingAsync(entry));
    }
    return results;
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(results => {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

Example:

```js
async function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    const results = [];
    for (const entry of theArray) {
        results.push(await doSomethingAsync(entry));
    }
    return results;
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3]).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
            resolve(value * 2);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you can't use ES2017+ syntax (yet), you can use a variation on the ["Promise reduce" pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433643/javascript-how-do-i-reduce-multiple-promise-all) (this is more complex than the usual Promise reduce because we're not passing the result from one into the next, but instead gathering up their results in an array):

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return theArray.reduce(function(p, entry) {
        return p.then(function(results) {
            return doSomethingAsync(entry).then(function(result) {
                results.push(result);
                return results;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve([]));
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return theArray.reduce(function(p, entry) {
        return p.then(function(results) {
            return doSomethingAsync(entry).then(function(result) {
                results.push(result);
                return results;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve([]));
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3]).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
            resolve(value * 2);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

...which is less cumbersome with [ES2015+ arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return theArray.reduce((p, entry) => p.then(results => doSomethingAsync(entry).then(result => {
        results.push(result);
        return results;
    })), Promise.resolve([]));
}
doSomethingWith(theArray).then(results => {
    console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

Example:

```js
function doSomethingWith(theArray) {
    return theArray.reduce((p, entry) => p.then(results => doSomethingAsync(entry).then(result => {
        results.push(result);
        return results;
    })), Promise.resolve([]));
}
doSomethingWith([1, 2, 3]).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});

function doSomethingAsync(value) {
    console.log("Starting async operation for " + value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Completing async operation for " + value);
            resolve(value * 2);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Could you explain how the `if (--expecting === 0)` part of the code works please? The callback version of your solution is working great for me, I just don't understand how, with that statement, you are checking the number of responses completed. Appreciate it's just lack of knowledge on my part. Is there an alternative way that check could be written?

Comment: @Sarah: `expecting` starts out with the value of `array.length`, which is how many requests we're going to make. We know the callback won't be called until all of those requests are started. In the callback, `if (--expecting === 0)` does this: 1. Decrements `expecting` (we've received a response, so we're expecting one fewer response) and if the value *after* the decrement is 0 (we're not expecting any more responses), we're done!

Comment: @Henke - I think it is indeed personal preference, and while normally I'd prefer to log raw data and let the console handle it, in this specific case I think you're right about the change. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Out of convenience for myself (and others?), adding a link to a related answer:
[How to make many asynchronous calls and wait for them all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426920).

Answer (score 184):

### Angular 1

People who are using [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS), can handle this situation using *promises*.

[Here](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/09/09/using-angularjs-promises/) it says,

> Promises can be used to unnest asynchronous functions and allows one to chain multiple functions together.

You can find a nice explanation [here](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) also.

An example found in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) mentioned below.

```
  promiseB = promiseA.then(
    function onSuccess(result) {
      return result + 1;
    }
    ,function onError(err) {
      // Handle error
    }
  );

 // promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved
 // and its value will be the result of promiseA incremented by 1.
```

### Angular 2 and later

In Angular 2 with look at the following example, but its [recommended](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/observables_vs_promises.html) to use *observables* with Angular 2.

```
 search(term: string) {
     return this.http
       .get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${term}&type=artist`)
       .map((response) => response.json())
       .toPromise();
}
```

You can consume that in this way,

```
search() {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchField.value)
      .then((result) => {
    this.result = result.artists.items;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

See the [original](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/requests_as_promises.html) post here. But TypeScript does not support [native ES6 Promises](http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/), if you want to use it, you might need plugin for that.

Additionally, here is the [promises specification](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec).

Comment: This does not explain how promises would solve this issue at all though.

Comment: jQuery and [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) methods both return promises as well.  I would suggest revising your answer.  Though jQuery's isn't quite the same (then is there, but catch isn't).

Answer (score 130):

**Have a look at this example:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    var getJoke = function(){
        return $http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').then(function(res){
            return res.data.value;  
        });
    }

    getJoke().then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.joke);
    });
});
```

As you can see `getJoke` is **returning a** resolved **promise** (it is resolved when returning `res.data.value`). So you wait until the **$http.get** request is completed and then **console.log(res.joke)** is executed (as a normal asynchronous flow).

**This is the plnkr:**

http://embed.plnkr.co/XlNR7HpCaIhJxskMJfSg/

**ES6 way (async - await)**

```
(function(){
  async function getJoke(){
    let response = await fetch('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data.value;
  }

  getJoke().then((joke) => {
    console.log(joke);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 128):

This is one of the places which **two-way data binding** or **store concept** that's used in many new JavaScript frameworks will work great for you...

So if you are using [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)), or any other frameworks which do two-way data binding or store concept, this issue is simply fixed for you, so in easy words, your result is `undefined` at the first stage, so you have got `result = undefined` before you receive the data, then as soon as you get the result, it will be updated and get assigned to the new value which response of your Ajax call...

But how you can do it in pure JavaScript or jQuery for example as you asked in this question?

You can use a callback, promise and recently observable to handle it for you. For example, in promises we have some function like `success()` or `then()` which will be executed when your data is ready for you. The same with callback or the *subscribe* function on an observable.

For example, in your case which you are using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo() {
        $.ajax({url: "api/data", success: function(data){
            fooDone(data); // After we have data, we pass it to fooDone
        }});
    };

    function fooDone(data) {
        console.log(data); // fooDone has the data and console.log it
    };

    foo(); // The call happens here
});
```

For more information, study promises and observables which are newer ways to do this async stuff.

Comment: This is fine at global scope, but in some module context you probably want to ensure right context for the callback e.g. `$.ajax({url: "api/data", success: fooDone.bind(this)});`

Comment: This is actually incorrect as React is one-way data binding

Comment: @MatthewBrent you are not wrong, but not right also, React props are object and if changed, they change throughout the application, but its not a way that React developer recommend to use it...

Answer (score 125):

It's a very common issue we face while struggling with the 'mysteries' of JavaScript. Let me try demystifying this mystery today.

Let's start with a simple JavaScript function:

```
function foo(){
    // Do something
    return 'wohoo';
}

let bar = foo(); // 'bar' is 'wohoo' here
```

That's a simple synchronous function call (where each line of code is 'finished with its job' before the next one in sequence), and the result is same as expected.

Now let's add a bit of twist, by introducing a little delay in our function, so that all lines of code are not 'finished' in sequence. Thus, it will emulate the asynchronous behavior of the function:

```
function foo(){
    setTimeout( ()=> {
        return 'wohoo';
   }, 1000)
}

let bar = foo() // 'bar' is undefined here
```

So there you go; that delay just broke the functionality we expected! But what exactly happened? Well, it's actually pretty logical if you look at the code.

The function `foo()`, upon execution, returns nothing (thus returned value is `undefined`), but it does start a timer, which executes a function after 1 second to return 'wohoo'. But as you can see, the value that's assigned to bar is the immediately returned stuff from foo(), which is nothing, i.e., just `undefined`.

**So, how do we tackle this issue?**

Let's ask our function for a *promise*.
Promise is really about what it means: it means that the function guarantees you to provide with any output it gets in future. So let's see it in action for our little problem above:

```
function foo(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // I want foo() to PROMISE me something
    setTimeout ( function(){
      // Promise is RESOLVED, when the execution reaches this line of code
       resolve('wohoo') // After 1 second, RESOLVE the promise with value 'wohoo'
    }, 1000 )
  })
}

let bar;
foo().then( res => {
    bar = res;
    console.log(bar) // Will print 'wohoo'
});
```

Thus, the summary is - to tackle the asynchronous functions like Ajax-based calls, etc., you can use a promise to `resolve` the value (which you intend to return). Thus, in short you **resolve** value instead of **returning**, in asynchronous functions.

### UPDATE (Promises with async/await)

Apart from using `then/catch` to work with promises, there exists one more approach. The idea is to *recognize an asynchronous function* and then *wait for the promises* to resolve, before moving to the next line of code. It's still just the `promises` under the hood, but with a different syntactical approach. To make things clearer, you can find a comparison below:

#### then/catch version:

```
function saveUsers(){
     getUsers()
      .then(users => {
         saveSomewhere(users);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
       })
 }
```

#### async/await version:

```
  async function saveUsers(){
     try{
        let users = await getUsers()
        saveSomewhere(users);
     }
     catch(err){
        console.error(err);
     }
  }
```

Comment: is this still considered the best way to return a value from a promise or async/await?

Comment: @edwardsmarkf Personally I don't think there's a best way as such. I use promises with then/catch , async/await as well as generators for async portions of my code. It largely depends on the context of usage.

Answer (score 116):

Another approach to return a value from an asynchronous function, is to pass in an object that will store the result from the asynchronous function.

Here is an example of the same:

```
var async = require("async");

// This wires up result back to the caller
var result = {};
var asyncTasks = [];
asyncTasks.push(function(_callback){
    // some asynchronous operation
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            result.response = response;
            _callback();
        }
    });
});

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
    // result is available after performing asynchronous operation
    console.log(result)
    console.log('Done');
});
```

I am using the `result` object to store the value during the asynchronous operation. This allows the result be available even after the asynchronous job.

I use this approach a lot. I would be interested to know how well this approach works where wiring the result back through consecutive modules is involved.

Comment: There is nothing special about using an object here. It would work as well if you assigned he response directly to `result`. It works because you are reading the variable *after* the async function is complete.

Answer (score 102):

While promises and callbacks work fine in many situations, it is a pain in the rear to express something like:

```
if (!name) {
  name = async1();
}
async2(name);
```

You'd end up going through `async1`; check if `name` is undefined or not and call the callback accordingly.

```
async1(name, callback) {
  if (name)
    callback(name)
  else {
    doSomething(callback)
  }
}

async1(name, async2)
```

While it is *okay* in small examples it gets annoying when you have a lot of similar cases and error handling involved.

`Fibers` helps in solving the issue.

```
var Fiber = require('fibers')

function async1(container) {
  var current = Fiber.current
  var result
  doSomething(function(name) {
    result = name
    fiber.run()
  })
  Fiber.yield()
  return result
}

Fiber(function() {
  var name
  if (!name) {
    name = async1()
  }
  async2(name)
  // Make any number of async calls from here
}
```

You can checkout the project [here](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).

Comment: is this similar to generator functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: Is this still relevant?

Comment: You can make use of `async-await` if you're using some of the newest versions of node. If someone is stuck with older versions they can use this method.

Answer (score 98):

The following example I have written shows how to

- Handle asynchronous HTTP calls;
- Wait for response from each API call;
- Use [Promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) pattern;
- Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) pattern to join multiple HTTP calls;

This working example is self-contained. It will define a simple request object that uses the window `XMLHttpRequest` object to make calls. It will define a simple function to wait for a bunch of promises to be completed.

Context. The example is querying the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/) endpoint in order to search for `playlist` objects for a given set of query strings:

```
[
 "search?type=playlist&q=%22doom%20metal%22",
 "search?type=playlist&q=Adele"
]
```

For each item, a new Promise will fire a block - `ExecutionBlock`, parse the result, schedule a new set of promises based on the result array, that is a list of Spotify `user` objects and execute the new HTTP call within the `ExecutionProfileBlock` asynchronously.

You can then see a nested Promise structure, that lets you spawn multiple and completely asynchronous nested HTTP calls, and join the results from each subset of calls through `Promise.all`.

**NOTE**
Recent Spotify `search` APIs will require an access token to be specified in the request headers:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"
```

So, you to run the following example you need to put your access token in the request headers:

```js
var spotifyAccessToken = "YourSpotifyAccessToken";
var console = {
    log: function(s) {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
    }
}

// Simple XMLHttpRequest
// based on https://davidwalsh.name/xmlhttprequest
SimpleRequest = {
    call: function(what, response) {
        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Internet Explorer
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                  request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        // State changes
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) { // Done
                if (request.status === 200) { // Complete
                    response(request.responseText)
                }
                else
                    response();
            }
        }
        request.open('GET', what, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + spotifyAccessToken);
        request.send(null);
    }
}

//PromiseAll
var promiseAll = function(items, block, done, fail) {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [],
                   index = 0;
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        promises.push(function(item, i) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                if (block) {
                    block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
                }
            });
        }(item, ++index))
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function AcceptHandler(results) {
        if (done) done(results);
    }, function ErrorHandler(error) {
        if (fail) fail(error);
    });
}; //promiseAll

// LP: deferred execution block
var ExecutionBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
    var url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
    url += item;
    console.log( url )
    SimpleRequest.call(url, function(result) {
        if (result) {

            var profileUrls = JSON.parse(result).playlists.items.map(function(item, index) {
                return item.owner.href;
            })
            resolve(profileUrls);
        }
        else {
            reject(new Error("call error"));
        }
    })
}

arr = [
    "search?type=playlist&q=%22doom%20metal%22",
    "search?type=playlist&q=Adele"
]

promiseAll(arr, function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Making request [" + index + "]")
    ExecutionBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
}, function(results) { // Aggregated results

    console.log("All profiles received " + results.length);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0], null, 2));

    ///// promiseall again

    var ExecutionProfileBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
        SimpleRequest.call(item, function(result) {
            if (result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                resolve({
                    name: obj.display_name,
                    followers: obj.followers.total,
                    url: obj.href
                });
            } //result
        })
    } //ExecutionProfileBlock

    promiseAll(results[0], function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
        //console.log("Making request [" + index + "] " + item)
        ExecutionProfileBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
    }, function(results) { // aggregated results
        console.log("All response received " + results.length);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    }

    , function(error) { // Error
        console.log(error);
    })

    /////

  },
  function(error) { // Error
      console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

I have extensively discussed this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536245/how-to-search-for-a-user-by-name-using-spotify-web-api/36537774#36537774).

Answer (score 96):

The short answer is, **you have to implement a callback like this:**

```
function callback(response) {
    // Here you can do what ever you want with the response object.
    console.log(response);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    success: callback
});
```

Answer (score 93):

> JavaScript is single threaded.

The browser can be divided into three parts:

1. Event Loop
2. Web API
3. Event Queue

The event loop runs for forever, i.e., kind of an infinite loop. The event queue is where all your functions are pushed on some event (example: click).

This is one by one carried out of queue and put into the event loop which executes this function and prepares itself for the next one after the first one is executed. This means execution of one function doesn't start until the function before it in the queue is executed in the event loop.

Now let us think we pushed two functions in a queue. One is for getting a data from the server and another utilises that data. We pushed the serverRequest() function in the queue first and then the utiliseData() function. The serverRequest function goes in the event loop and makes a call to server as we never know how much time it will take to get data from server, so this process is expected to take time and so we busy our event loop thus hanging our page.

That's where Web API come into the role. It takes this function from the event loop and deals with the server making the event loop free, so that we can execute the next function from the queue.

The next function in the queue is utiliseData() which goes in the loop, but because of no data available, it goes to waste and execution of the next function continues until the end of the queue. (This is called Async calling, i.e., we can do something else until we get data.)

Let us suppose our serverRequest() function had a return statement in code. When we get back data from the server Web API, it will push it in the queue at the end of queue.

As it gets pushed at the end of the queue, we cannot utilise its data as there isn't any function left in our queue to utilise this data. **Thus it is not possible to return something from the async call.**

Thus the *solution* to this is *callback* or *promise*.

- An *image* from [one of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/38898933#38898933) correctly explains callback use...*

We give our function (function utilising data returned from the server) to a function calling the server.

[image: Callback]

```
function doAjax(callbackFunc, method, url) {
    var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpReq.open(method, url);
    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpReq.status == 200) {
            callbackFunc(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttpReq.send(null);
}
```

In my *code* it is called as:

```
function loadMyJson(categoryValue){
    if(categoryValue === "veg")
        doAjax(print, "GET", "http://localhost:3004/vegetables");
    else if(categoryValue === "fruits")
        doAjax(print, "GET", "http://localhost:3004/fruits");
    else
      console.log("Data not found");
}
```

[JavaScript.info callback](https://javascript.info/callbacks)

Answer (score 89):

## 2017 answer: you can now do exactly what you want in every current browser and [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)

This is quite simple:

- Return a Promise
- Use the ['await'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), which will tell JavaScript to await the promise to be resolved into a value (like the HTTP response)
- Add the ['async'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword to the parent function

Here's a working version of your code:

```
(async function(){

    var response = await superagent.get('...')
    console.log(response)

})()
```

[await is supported in all current browsers and Node.js 8](http://caniuse.com/#search=await)

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only with functions that return promises – for example it doesn't work with Node.js API, which uses callbacks. And I wouldn't recommend using it without Babel, because not everyone uses "current browsers".

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski node 8 includes https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original which can be used to make the node.js API return promises. Whether you have the time and money to support non-current browsers obviously depends on your situation.

Comment: IE 11 is still a current browser in 2018, sadly and it doesn't support `await/async`

Comment: IE11 is not a current browser. It was released 5 years ago, has a worldwide market share of 2.5% according to caniuse, and unless someone is doubling your budget to ignore all current tech then it's not worth most people's time.

Answer (score 74):

You can use this custom library (written using Promise) to make a remote call.

```
function $http(apiConfig) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open(apiConfig.method, apiConfig.url);
        client.send();
        client.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                // Performs the function "resolve" when this.status is equal to 2xx.
                // Your logic here.
                resolve(this.response);
            }
            else {
                // Performs the function "reject" when this.status is different than 2xx.
                reject(this.statusText);
            }
        };
        client.onerror = function () {
            reject(this.statusText);
        };
    });
}
```

Simple usage example:

```
$http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'google.com'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 74):

Another solution is to execute code via the sequential executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs).

### If the underlying function is promisified

nsynjs will evaluate all promises sequentially, and put the promise result into the `data` property:

```js
function synchronousCode() {

    var getURL = function(url) {
        return window.fetch(url).data.text().data;
    };
    
    var url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js';
    console.log('received bytes:',getURL(url).length);
    
};

nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},function(){
    console.log('synchronousCode done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amaksr/nsynjs/master/nsynjs.js"></script>
```

### If the underlying function is not promisified

Step 1. Wrap the function with a callback into the nsynjs-aware wrapper (if it has a promisified version, you can skip this step):

```
var ajaxGet = function (ctx,url) {
    var res = {};
    var ex;
    $.ajax(url)
    .done(function (data) {
        res.data = data;
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
        ex = e;
    })
    .always(function() {
        ctx.resume(ex);
    });
    return res;
};
ajaxGet.nsynjsHasCallback = true;
```

Step 2. Put synchronous logic into function:

```
function process() {
    console.log('got data:', ajaxGet(nsynjsCtx, "data/file1.json").data);
}
```

Step 3. Run function in synchronous manner via nsynjs:

```
nsynjs.run(process,this,function () {
    console.log("synchronous function finished");
});
```

Nsynjs will evaluate all operators and expressions step-by-step, pausing execution in case if the result of some slow function is not ready.

More examples are [here](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples).

Comment: This is interesting. I like how it allows to code async calls the way you'd do it in other languages. But technically it's not real JavaScript?

Answer (score 52):

#### 1. A first stumbling step

As for many others, my encounter with asynchronous calls was puzzling at first. 
I don't remember the details, but I may have tried something like:

```js
let result;

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log('\nInside $.ajax:');
    console.log(response);
    result = response;
  },
});

console.log('Finally, the result: ' + result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Whoops!* 
The output of the line
`console.log('Finally, the result: ' + result);`
which I thought would be printed *last*, is printed *before* the other output! 
– And it doesn't contain the result: it just prints `undefined`. <sup>1</sup> 
How come?

###### A helpful insight

I distinctly remember my first *aha* () moment about asynchronous calls.
It was :

> [you actually don't want to get the data *out* of a callback; you want to get your data-needing action *into* the callback!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298196#comment75602602_44298196)
> <sup>2</sup>

This is true in the example above.

#### 2. Plain JavaScript and a callback function

Luckily, it is possible to write code *after* the asynchronous call that deals with the response once it has completed.

One alternative is the use of a *callback* function in a [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) :
<sup>3</sup>

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2';

function asynchronousFunc(callback) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {
      console.log('The request is done. Now calling back.');
      callback(request.responseText);
    }
  };
}

asynchronousFunc(function (result) {
  console.log('This is the start of the callback function. Result:');
  console.log(result);
  console.log('The callback function finishes on this line. THE END!');
});

console.log('LAST in the code, but executed FIRST!');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note how the function `asynchronousFunc` is `void`. It returns nothing. 
`asynchronousFunc` is called with an anonymous callback function, 
(`asynchronousFunc(function (result) {...});`). 
This executes the desired actions on the result *after* the request has completed – when the `responseText` is available.

Running the above snippet shows how I will probably not want to write any code *after* the asynchronous call (such as the line
`LAST in the code, but executed FIRST!`). 
*Why?* – Because such code will run *before* the asynchronous call delivers any response data. 
Doing so is bound to cause confusion when comparing the *code* with the *output*.

#### 3. Promise with `.then()`

The `.then()` construct was introduced in the *ECMA-262 6th Edition in June 2015*. 
The code below is plain JavaScript, replacing the old-school *XMLHttpRequest* with [*Fetch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). <sup>4</sup>

```js
fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseBody) => {
    console.log('Using .then() :');
    console.log(responseBody.value + '\n');
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### 4. Promise with `async`/`await`

The `async`/`await` construct was introduced in the *ECMA-262 8th Edition in June 2017*.

```js
async function awaitAndReceivePromise() {
  const responseBody = (
    await fetch('https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random')
  ).json();
  console.log('Using async/await:');
  const obj = (await responseBody)[0];
  console.log('"' + obj.content + '" – ' + obj.author + '\n');
}

awaitAndReceivePromise();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A word of warning is warranted if you decide to go with the `async`/`await` construct.
Note in the above snippet how `await` is needed in *two* places. 
If forgotten in the first place, there will be no output at all.
If forgotten in the second place, the only output will be `Using async/await:` – nothing else gets printed. 
Forgetting the `async` prefix of the function is maybe the worst of all – you'll get a `"SyntaxError"` – and likely *no hint about the missing* `async` keyword.

---

All the above examples succinctly convey how asynchronous calls may be used on toyish APIs. <sup>5</sup>

### References

- [Some questions and answers about asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662000)
- [Using plain JavaScript and a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593)
- [Continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)
- [XMLHttpRequest at mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [XMLHttpRequest: onload vs. onreadystatechange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19247992)
- [XMLHttpRequest.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)
- [An example demonstrating `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415961)
- [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [The XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org)
- [The Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org)
- [The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG)](https://whatwg.org/news/start)
- [Links to ECMA specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources)
- [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Expressed by the asker of the question as *they all return `undefined`*.

<sup>2</sup>
Here is more on how [asynchronous calls may be confusing at first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662000).

<sup>3</sup>
Like the *X* in *AJAX*, the name `XMLHttpRequest` is misleading – [it can be used to retrieve any type of data, not just XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). 
These days, the data format of Web APIs is ubiquitously JSON, not XML.

<sup>4</sup>
[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).
I was surprised to learn that neither *XMLHttpRequest* nor *Fetch* are part of the *ECMAScript* standard.
The reason JavaScript can access them here is that the web browser provides them. 
[The Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org) and [the XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org) are both upheld by [the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group](https://whatwg.org/news/start) which was formed in June 2004. \

<sup>5</sup>
You might also be interested in
[How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337).

Answer (score 46):

ECMAScript 6 has 'generators' which allow you to easily program in an asynchronous style.

```
function* myGenerator() {
    const callback = yield;
    let [response] = yield $.ajax("https://stackoverflow.com", {complete: callback});
    console.log("response is:", response);

    // examples of other things you can do
    yield setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    console.log("it delayed for 1000ms");
    while (response.statusText === "error") {
        [response] = yield* anotherGenerator();
    }
}
```

To run the above code you do this:

```
const gen = myGenerator(); // Create generator
gen.next(); // Start it
gen.next((...args) => gen.next([...args])); // Set its callback function
```

If you need to target browsers that don't support ES6 you can run the code through Babel or closure-compiler to generate ECMAScript 5.

The callback `...args` are wrapped in an array and destructured when you read them so that the pattern can cope with callbacks that have multiple arguments. For example with [node fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

```
const [err, data] = yield fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", callback);
```

Comment: Do you consider generators / async generators to be an async API solution alone ? Or you would use generators to wrap another asynchronous API like promise/deffered ? I agree it is another strong addition to the async universe but still haven't found the right usage of generators that would make me adopt them.

Answer (score 44):

We find ourselves in a universe which appears to progress along a dimension we call "time". We don't really understand what time is, but we have developed abstractions and vocabulary that let us reason and talk about it: "past", "present", "future", "before", "after".

The computer systems we build--more and more--have time as an important dimension. Certain things are set up to happen in the future. Then other things need to happen after those first things eventually occur. This is the basic notion called "asynchronicity". In our increasingly networked world, the most common case of asynchronicity is waiting for some remote system to respond to some request.

Consider an example. You call the milkman and order some milk. When it comes, you want to put it in your coffee. You can't put the milk in your coffee right now, because it is not here yet. You have to wait for it to come before putting it in your coffee. In other words, the following won't work:

```
var milk = order_milk();
put_in_coffee(milk);
```

Because JavaScript has no way to know that it needs to **wait** for `order_milk` to finish before it executes `put_in_coffee`. In other words, it does not know that `order_milk` is **asynchronous**--is something that is not going to result in milk until some future time. JavaScript, and other declarative languages execute one statement after another without waiting.

The classic JavaScript approach to this problem, taking advantage of the fact that JavaScript supports functions as first-class objects which can be passed around, is to pass a function as a parameter to the asynchronous request, which it will then invoke when it has completed its task sometime in the future. That is the "callback" approach. It looks like this:

```
order_milk(put_in_coffee);
```

`order_milk` kicks off, orders the milk, then, when and only when it arrives, it invokes `put_in_coffee`.

The problem with this callback approach is that it pollutes the normal semantics of a function reporting its result with `return`; instead, functions must not reports their results by calling a callback given as a parameter. Also, this approach can rapidly become unwieldy when dealing with longer sequences of events. For example, let's say that I want to wait for the milk to be put in the coffee, and then and only then perform a third step, namely drinking the coffee. I end up needing to write something like this:

```
order_milk(function(milk) { put_in_coffee(milk, drink_coffee); }
```

where I am passing to `put_in_coffee` both the milk to put in it, and also the action (`drink_coffee`) to execute once the milk has been put in. Such code becomes hard to write, and read, and debug.

In this case, we could rewrite the code in the question as:

```
var answer;
$.ajax('/foo.json') . done(function(response) {
  callback(response.data);
});

function callback(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

#### Enter promises

This was the motivation for the notion of a "promise", which is a particular type of value which represents a **future** or **asynchronous** outcome of some sort. It can represent something that already happened, or that is going to happen in the future, or might never happen at all. Promises have a single method, named `then`, to which you pass an action to be executed when the outcome the promise represents has been realized.

In the case of our milk and coffee, we design `order_milk` to return a promise for the milk arriving, then specify `put_in_coffee` as a `then` action, as follows:

```
order_milk() . then(put_in_coffee)
```

One advantage of this is that we can string these together to create sequences of future occurrences ("chaining"):

```
order_milk() . then(put_in_coffee) . then(drink_coffee)
```

Let's apply promises to your particular problem. We will wrap our request logic inside a function, which returns a promise:

```
function get_data() {
  return $.ajax('/foo.json');
}
```

Actually, all we've done is added a `return` to the call to `$.ajax`. This works because jQuery's `$.ajax` already returns a kind of promise-like thing. (In practice, without getting into details, we would prefer to wrap this call so as for return a real promise, or use some alternative to `$.ajax` that does so.) Now, if we want to load the file and wait for it to finish and then do something, we can simply say

```
get_data() . then(do_something)
```

for instance,

```
get_data() .
  then(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

When using promises, we end up passing lots of functions into `then`, so it's often helpful to use the more compact ES6-style arrow functions:

```
get_data() .
  then(data => console.log(data));
```

#### The `async` keyword

But there's still something vaguely dissatisfying about having to write code one way if synchronous and a quite different way if asynchronous. For synchronous, we write

```
a();
b();
```

but if `a` is asynchronous, with promises we have to write

```
a() . then(b);
```

Above, we said, "JavaScript has no way to know that it needs to **wait** for the first call to finish before it executes the second". Wouldn't it be nice if there **was** some way to tell JavaScript that? It turns out that there is--the `await` keyword, used inside a special type of function called an "async" function. This feature is part of the upcoming version of ECMAScript (ES), but it is already available in transpilers such as [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) given the right presets. This allows us to simply write

```
async function morning_routine() {
  var milk   = await order_milk();
  var coffee = await put_in_coffee(milk);
  await drink(coffee);
}
```

In your case, you would be able to write something like

```
async function foo() {
  data = await get_data();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 43):

### Here are some approaches to work with asynchronous requests:

1. [Browser Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
2. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) - A promise library for JavaScript
3. [A+ Promises.js](https://www.promisejs.org/)
4. [jQuery deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)
5. [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
6. Using callback concept - As implementation in first answer

#### Example: jQuery deferred implementation to work with multiple requests

```js
var App = App || {};

App = {
    getDataFromServer: function(){

      var self = this,
                 deferred = $.Deferred(),
                 requests = [];

      requests.push($.getJSON('request/ajax/url/1'));
      requests.push($.getJSON('request/ajax/url/2'));

      $.when.apply(jQuery, requests).done(function(xhrResponse) {
        return deferred.resolve(xhrResponse.result);
      });
      return deferred;
    },

    init: function(){

        this.getDataFromServer().done(_.bind(function(resp1, resp2) {

           // Do the operations which you wanted to do when you
           // get a response from Ajax, for example, log response.
        }, this));
    }
};
App.init();
```

Comment: Why include a Stack Snippet that outputs an error?

Answer (score 42):

**Short answer**: Your `foo()` method returns immediately, while the `$ajax()` call executes asynchronously *after the function returns*. The problem is then how or where to store the results retrieved by the async call once it returns.

Several solutions have been given in this thread. Perhaps the easiest way is to pass an object to the `foo()` method, and to store the results in a member of that object after the async call completes.

```
function foo(result) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            result.response = response;   // Store the async result
        }
    });
}

var result = { response: null };   // Object to hold the async result
foo(result);                       // Returns before the async completes
```

Note that the call to `foo()` will still return nothing useful. However, the result of the async call will now be stored in `result.response`.

Comment: While this works, it's not really better than assigning to a global variable.

Answer (score 41):

Use a `callback()` function inside the `foo()` success.
Try it in this way. It is simple and easy to understand.

```
var lat = "";
var lon = "";

function callback(data) {
    lat = data.lat;
    lon = data.lon;
}

function getLoc() {
    var url = "http://ip-api.com/json"
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}

getLoc();
```

Answer (score 36):

## Using Promise

The most perfect answer to this question is using `Promise`.

```
function ajax(method, url, params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.send(params);
  });
}
```

### Usage

```
ajax("GET", "/test", "acrive=1").then(function(result) {
    // Code depending on result
})
.catch(function() {
    // An error occurred
});
```

---

## But wait...!

There is a problem with using promises!

### Why should we use our own custom Promise?

I was using this solution for a while until I figured out there is an error in old browsers:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

So I decided to implement my own Promise class for **ES3 to below** JavaScript compilers if it's not defined. Just add this code before your main code and then safely use Promise!

```
if(typeof Promise === "undefined"){
    function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; return 

    _typeof = "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && "function" == typeof Symbol && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }, _typeof(obj); }
    function _toConsumableArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }
    function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."); }
    function _unsupportedIterableToArray(o, minLen) { if (!o) return; if (typeof o === "string") return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8, -1); if (n === "Object" && o.constructor) n = o.constructor.name; if (n === "Map" || n === "Set") return Array.from(o); if (n === "Arguments" || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); }
    function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && iter[Symbol.iterator] != null || iter["@@iterator"] != null) return Array.from(iter); }
    function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return _arrayLikeToArray(arr); }
    function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) { if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length; for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) arr2[i] = arr[i]; return arr2; }
    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
    function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, _toPropertyKey(descriptor.key), descriptor); } }
    function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); Object.defineProperty(Constructor, "prototype", { writable: false }); return Constructor; }
    function _toPropertyKey(arg) { var key = _toPrimitive(arg, "string"); return _typeof(key) === "symbol" ? key : String(key); }
    function _toPrimitive(input, hint) { if (_typeof(input) !== "object" || input === null) return input; var prim = input[Symbol.toPrimitive]; if (prim !== undefined) { var res = prim.call(input, hint || "default"); if (_typeof(res) !== "object") return res; throw new TypeError("@@toPrimitive must return a primitive value."); } return (hint === "string" ? String : Number)(input); }
    var Promise = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  "use strict";

  function Promise(main) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Promise);
    this.main = main;
    this.mainExecuted = false;
    this.resolved = false;
    this.rejected = false;
    this.promiseChain = [];
    this.handleError = function () {};
    this.onResolve = this.onResolve.bind(this);
    this.onReject = this.onReject.bind(this);
  }
  _createClass(Promise, [{
    key: "then",
    value: function then(handleSuccess) {
      if (this.resolved) {
        if (!this.rejected) {
          this.args = handleSuccess(this.args);
        }
      } else {
        this.promiseChain.push(handleSuccess);
        this.main(this.onResolve, this.onReject);
        this.thenExecuted = true;
      }
      return this;
    }
  }, {
    key: "catch",
    value: function _catch(handleError) {
      this.handleError = handleError;
      if (!this.mainExecuted) {
        this.main(this.onResolve, this.onReject);
        this.thenExecuted = true;
      }
      return this;
    }
  }, {
    key: "onResolve",
    value: function onResolve() {
      var _this = this;
      this.resolved = true;
      for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
        args[_key] = arguments[_key];
      }
      this.args = args;
      try {
        this.promiseChain.forEach(function (nextFunction) {
          _this.args = nextFunction.apply(void 0, _toConsumableArray(_this.args));
        });
      } catch (error) {
        this.promiseChain = [];
        this.onReject(error);
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: "onReject",
    value: function onReject(error) {
      this.rejected = true;
      this.handleError(error);
    }
  }]);
  return Promise;
}();
}
```

Comment: I reckon you could also use a callback :D, but this is incredible.

Comment: core-js existed in 2018. No reason to invent your own promise. Looks cool anyways.

Answer (score 35):

Using ES2017 you should have this as the function declaration.

```
async function foo() {
  var response = await $.ajax({url: '...'})
  return response;
}
```

And executing it like this.

```
(async function() {
  try {
    var result = await foo()
    console.log(result)
  } catch (e) {}
})()
```

Or the Promise syntax.

```
foo().then(response => {
  console.log(response)

}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)

})
```

Stack Snippet that demonstrates the code above.

```js
// The function declaration:
async function foo() {
  var response = await $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  })
  return response;
}

// Execute it like this:
(async function() {
  try {
    var result = await foo()
    console.log(result)
  } catch (e) {}
})()

// Or use Promise syntax:
foo().then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could that second function to reuseable??

Comment: How do you use the results if oncolse,log is called? Doesn't everything just go to the console at that point?

Comment: This is a fine and helpful answer that clearly demonstrates how to correctly use the `async` - `await` duality feature. One thing to note is that `async` and `await` are actually not needed in the function `foo()`. (Remove them both and the code still runs just fine.)
This is because `foo()` returns a Promise, and as long as the code receiving the Promise _awaits_ it, everything will be fine. ~ * ~ * ~ * ~
Note: the `async` - `await` feature was introduced in the
[ECMA-262 8th Edition in June 2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources).

Comment: I have a requirement to return some data after calculation from the callback function. How could i do that

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 32):

Of course there are many approaches like synchronous request, promise, but from my experience I think you should use the callback approach. It's natural to asynchronous behavior of JavaScript.

So, your code snippet can be rewritten to be a little different:

```
function foo() {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            myCallback(response);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

function myCallback(response) {
    // Does something.
}
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently asynchronous about callbacks or JavaScript.

Comment: Why keep `var result;` and `return result;`? The latter will still _always_ return `undefined`!

Answer (score 32):

The question was:

> How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?

which *can* be interpreted as:

> How to make **asynchronous** code look **synchronous**?

The solution will be to avoid callbacks, and use a combination of **Promises** and **async/await**.

I would like to give an example for an Ajax request.

(Although it can be written in JavaScript, I prefer to write it in Python, and compile it to JavaScript using [Transcrypt](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt). It will be clear enough.)

Let’s first enable jQuery usage, to have `$` available as `S`:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')
```

Define a function which returns a **Promise**, in this case an Ajax call:

```
def read(url: str):
    deferred = S.Deferred()
    S.ajax({'type': "POST", 'url': url, 'data': { },
        'success': lambda d: deferred.resolve(d),
        'error': lambda e: deferred.reject(e)
    })
    return deferred.promise()
```

Use the **asynchronous** code as if it were **synchronous**:

```
async def readALot():
    try:
        result1 = await read("url_1")
        result2 = await read("url_2")
    except Exception:
        console.warn("Reading a lot failed")
```

Comment: Anyone interested in using `async` / `await` will likely also want to read
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415961) (and possibly my comment below it :-).

Answer (score 31):

After reading all the responses here and with my experiences, I would like to resume the detail of `callback, promise and async/await` for the asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

**1) Callback:** The fundamental reason for a callback is to run code in response of an event (see the example below). We use callback in JavaScript every time.

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
function callback() {
  console.log('Hello');
}
body.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

But if you must use many nested callbacks in the example below, it will be fairy terrible for the code refactoring.

```
asyncCallOne(function callback1() {
  asyncCallTwo(function callback2() {
    asyncCallThree(function callback3() {
        ...
    })
  })
})
```

**2) Promise:** a syntax ES6 - Promise resolves the callback hell issue!

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
  // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code.
  // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR request or an HTML5 API.
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Success!")  // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 250)
})

myFirstPromise
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

myFirstPromise is a Promise instance that represents the process of async codes. The resolve function signals that the Promise instance has finished. Afterwards, we can call .then() (a chain of .then as you want) and .catch() on the promise instance:

```
then — Runs a callback you pass to it when the promise has fulfilled.
catch — Runs a callback you pass to it when something went wrong.
```

**3) Async/Await:** a new syntax ES6 - Await is basically syntactic sugar for Promise!

The Async function provides us with a clean and concise syntax that enables us to write less code to accomplish the same outcome we would get with promises. **Async/Await looks similar to synchronous code**, and synchronous code is much easier to read and write. To catch errors with Async/Await, we can use the block `try...catch`. In here, you don't need to write a chain of .then() of Promise syntax.

```
const getExchangeRate = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://getExchangeRateData');
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

getExchangeRate();
```

> Conclusion: These are totally the three syntaxes for asynchronous
> programming in JavaScript that you should well understand. **So if possible, I
> recommend that you should use "promise" or "async/await" for
> refactoring your asynchronous codes (mostly for XHR requests)** !

Comment: Hi, although this answer's contents are accurate, it really doesn't answer OP's question (which is how to return something from an asynchronous call?)

Answer (score 30):

Rather than throwing code at you, there are two concepts that are key to understanding how JavaScript handles callbacks and asynchronicity (is that even a word?)

### **[The Event Loop and Concurrency Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)**

There are three things you need to be aware of; **The queue; [the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop) and the stack**

In broad, simplistic terms, the event loop is like the project manager, it is constantly listening for any functions that want to run and communicates between the queue and the stack.

```
while (queue.waitForMessage()) {
  queue.processNextMessage();
}
```

Once it receives a message to run something it adds it to the queue. The queue is the list of things that are waiting to execute (like your AJAX request). imagine it like this:

1. call foo.com/api/bar using foobarFunc
2. Go perform an infinite loop
   ... and so on

When one of these messages is going to execute it pops the message from the queue and creates a stack, the stack is everything JavaScript needs to execute to perform the instruction in the message. So in our example it's being told to call `foobarFunc`

```
function foobarFunc (var) {
  console.log(anotherFunction(var));
}
```

So anything that foobarFunc needs to execute (in our case `anotherFunction`) will get pushed onto the stack. executed, and then forgotten about - the event loop will then move onto the next thing in the queue (or listen for messages)

**The key thing here is the order of execution. That is**

### **WHEN is something going to run**

When you make a call using AJAX to an external party or run any asynchronous code (a setTimeout for example), JavaScript is dependant upon a response before it can proceed.

The big question is when will it get the response? The answer is we don't know - so the event loop is waiting for that message to say "hey run me". If JavaScript just waited around for that message synchronously your app would freeze and it will suck. So JavaScript carries on executing the next item in the queue whilst waiting for the message to get added back to the queue.

That's why with asynchronous functionality we use things called **callbacks**. - A function or handler that, when passed into another function, will be executed at a later date. A [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) uses callbacks (functions passed to `.then()` for example) as a way to reason about this asynchronous behaviour in a more linear way. The promise is a way of saying "I *promise to return something at some point*" and the callback is how we handle that value that is eventually returned. jQuery uses specific callbacks called `deffered.done` `deffered.fail` and `deffered.always` (amongst others). You can see them all [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

So what you need to do is pass a function that is promised to execute at some point with data that is passed to it.

Because a callback is not executed immediately but at a later time it's important to pass the reference to the function not it executed. so

```
function foo(bla) {
  console.log(bla)
}
```

so most of the time (but not always) you'll pass `foo` not `foo()`

Hopefully that will make some sense. When you encounter things like this that seem confusing - i highly recommend reading the documentation fully to at least get an understanding of it. It will make you a much better developer.

Comment: I am struggling to accept "callbacks are kind of like promises". it's like saying "flour is kind of like bread" but it is not. you use flour, water and other incredients, mix them and eventually after a process, bread is the results.

Comment: This is true - I think I was try to say something that doesnt quite read what I was meaning. A promise in JS evidently represents something different to a callback, however when programming any kind asynchronous functionality you are going to be executing a callback. A promise represents the value but the callback is what we need to do something with that value, at some point in the future, when it returns.

Comment: A promise is mostly useless (but not always) without a callback to do something with the resolved value

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example that works:

```js
const validateName = async userName => {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
};

validateName("user")
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yet another fine answer demonstrating the use of `async` - `await`. ~ * ~
The `async` - `await` feature was introduced in the
[ECMA-262 8th Edition in June 2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources).

Answer (score 24):

### Await

A request works in an asynchronous way, so you can't read the data synchronously as in typical code. However, using `async/await` you can create asynchronous code which looks close/similar to the usual synchronous/sequential style. Code which processes response data needs to be wrapped by an `async` function (`load` in the below snippet) and inside it you need to add the `await` keyword before `foo()` (which also uses `async/await`).

```js
async function foo() {
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  var result = (await fetch(url)).text(); // Or .json()
  return result;
}

async function load() {
  var result = await foo();
  console.log(result);
}

load();
```

Remember that an `async` function always (implicitly) wraps its result into a promise (so it returns a promise).

Comment: Nice answer! Apparently, the `async` - `await` construct was introduced in the [ECMAScript 2017 Language Specification in June 2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources).

Answer (score 17):

**Let's see the forest first before looking at the trees.**

There are many informative answers with great details here, I won't repeat any of them. The key to programming in JavaScript is having first the **correct mental model** of overall execution.

1. Your entry point(s) is executed as the result of an event. For
   example, a script tag with code is loaded into the browser.
   (Accordingly, this is why you may need to be concerned with the
   readiness of the page to run your code if it requires DOM elements
   to be constructed first, etc.)
2. Your code executes to completion--however many asynchronous calls it
   makes--without executing **any** of your callbacks, including XHR
   requests, set timeouts, DOM event handlers, etc. Each of those callbacks waiting to be executed will sit in a queue, waiting their turn to be run after other events that fired have all finished execution.
3. Each individual callback to an XHR request, set timeout or DOM
   the event once invoked will then run to completion.

The good news is that if you understand this point well, you will never have to worry about race conditions. You should first and foremost thing of how you want to organize your code as essentially the response to different discrete events, and how you want to thread them together into a logical sequence.  You can use promises or higher level new async/await as tools to that end, or you can roll your own.

But you shouldn't use any tactical tools to solve a problem until you are comfortable with the actual problem domain. Draw a map of these dependencies to know what needs to run when. Attempting an ad-hoc approach to all these callbacks is just not going to serve you well.

Answer (score 14):

There is no way you can directly return the result of an Ajax response from a function. The reason is that an Ajax call (`$.get()` or `$.post()`) is asynchronous and calling the function that encapsulates the Ajax call would return even before the response is rendered.

In such scenarios, the only option is to return a promise object, to be resolved when the response arrives.

There are two ways by which the above issue can be resolved.
Both make use of a promise.

The code snippets below include a JSON URL. Both work and can be directly copied to [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle) and tested.

**Option #1 - return the Ajax call directly from the foo method.**
In the latest version of jQuery, an Ajax call returns a promise object, which can be resolved using a `.then` function. In code, the `.then` function is preceded by the call back function to be resolved, `foo()` in this case.

```js
   // Declare function foo
   function foo(url)
   {
     return $.get(url);
   }

   // Invoke the foo function, which returns a promise object
   // the 'then' function accepts the call back to the resolve function
   foo('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
     .then(function(response)
     {
       console.log(response);
     })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Option #2 - declare a promise object and return it.**
Declare a promise object inside the function, encapsulate the Ajax call within that promise function and return the promise object.

```js
   function foo1() {
     var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
     {
       $.ajax({
       url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
       success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
           resolve(response);
           // return response; // <- I tried that one as well
         }
       });
     });
     return promise;
   }

   foo1()
   .then(function(response)
   {
     console.log('Promise resolved:');
     console.log(response);
   })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Originally, callbacks were used for asynchronous operations (e.g., in the [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)). Now promise-based APIs like the browser's [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) have become the default solution and the nicer [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax is supported by all modern browsers and on Node.js (server side).

A common scenario - fetching JSON data from the server - can look like this:

```
async function fetchResource(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.statusText);
  }
  return res.json();
}
```

To use it in another function:

```
async function doSomething() {
  try {
    const data = await fetchResource("https://example.test/resource/1");
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error
    ...
  }
}
```

If you design a modern API, it is strongly recommended to prefer promise-based style over callbacks. If you inherited an API that relies on callbacks, it is possible to wrap it as a promise:

```
function sleep(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, timeout);
  });
}

async function fetchAfterTwoSeconds(url) {
  await sleep(2000);
  return fetchResource(url);
}
```

In Node.js, which historically relied exclusively on callbacks, that technique is so common that they added a helper function called [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Answer (score 9):

I think no matter what method or mechanism used, or whatever the framework is (Angular/React) that hides it from you, the following principle holds:

1. In the flow of the program (think code or even the lowest level: machine code), the data may not arrive back 2 seconds later, 3 seconds later, or may not arrive at all, so there is no usual `return` to use in order to return the data.
2. It is the classic "observer pattern". (It can be in the form of a "callback".) It is: "hey, I am interested in knowing a successful arrival of data; would you let me know when it does." So you register an observer to be notified (or a function to be called to notify about the successful arrival of the data.) You also usually register an observer for the failure of arrival of such data.
3. When it is successful arrival of data, or a failure of the return of such data, the registered observers (or callbacks) are notified together with the data (or called with the data). If the observer is registered in the form of a callback function `foo`, then `foo(data)` will be called. If the observer is registered in the form of an object `foo`, then depending on the interface, it could be that `foo.notify(data)` is called.

Comment: what do you mean by "It is the classic observer pattern". callback is not the classic observer pattern. maybe promise is a variation of the classic observer pattern, or a variation of PubSub, etc . . but by no means callback itself. at least the way I see it. Do you claim all kinds of async patterns are implementation of the classic observer pattern ? (event RXJS Observable isn't. even though rxjs.subject is)

Comment: I mean it in the way that "result is not ready, and let me know when it is ready (or has changed)" So for the question "How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?", it is "using a mechanism to get notified when there is result".  I guess you can say it is different because observer pattern can be invoked many times but this "callback" or "promise" is only one time?  I focus on the "notify me in the future when it is ready", instead of "how many times it can get called".

Comment: well I argue only about your naming, the choice of words. that callback is 'the classic observer pattern' which is a very specific design pattern that you can say Promise is a variation of. but callback (although it's a tool for notifying) is not the classic observer pattern. in promise we can push subscribers that will get notified when the promise settles, but callback is more like an atomic unit and not a pattern, IMHO.

Comment: ok it is about the naming... what I wanted to put through was, it is the classic "notify me when ready" kind of pattern

Answer (score 4):

Use of `async/await` with a transpilers like [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) to get it working in older browsers. You’ll also have to install this Babel preset and polyfill from npm: `npm i -D babel-preset-env babel-polyfill`.

```
function getData(ajaxurl) { 
  return $.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'GET',
  });
};

async test() {
  try {
    const res = await getData('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random')
    console.log(res)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

test();
```

Or the `.then` callback is just another way to write the same logic.

```
getData(ajaxurl).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### async: false

I solved it by setting `async` to false and restructure my Ajax call:

I set a global function called `sendRequest(type, url, data)` with three parameters to be called every time everywhere:

```
function sendRequest(type, url, data) {
    let returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            returnValue = resp;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now call the function:

```
let password = $("#password").val();
        let email = $("#email").val();
        let data = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        };
        let  resp =  sendRequest('POST', 'http://localhost/signin')}}", data);
        console.log(resp);
```

> Important **Note** in code is :  `async: false`

If this solution is not working with you, please note this may not working in some of browsers or [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) versions.

Comment: This technically solves the issue, but note that this is not recommended because it will freeze the window until the request completes. It's better to learn how to deal with the asynchronous nature of JS than to use synchronous versions of IO-related functions.

Comment: Using `async:false` is a terrible practice and should **never ever** be used. It was deprecated by browser vendors years before this answer was written. They even give you warnings in dev tools console not to use it when it is encountered

Comment: This is not AJAX, this is SJAX.

Answer (score -1):

I follow these two ways `Promises` and  `async/await`

Promises:

```
function makeAsyncCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = 'Async response';
      resolve(response);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

makeAsyncCall()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response); 
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error); 
  });
```

And async/await:

```
async function makeAsyncCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = 'Async response';
      resolve(response);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function handleAsyncCall() {
  try {
    const response = await makeAsyncCall();
    console.log(response); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); 
  }
}

handleAsyncCall();
```

Answer (score -1):

In JS, when an asynchronous function is called, it returns a Promise. If you want to return a value from the function, you need to ensure you are properly handling this Promise.

There is an example:

```
async function foo() {
  var res;
  await asyncRequest().then(function(response) {
    res = response;
  });
  return res;
}
```

// Call the function and handle it's result:

```
foo().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

In the above code, foo is an asynchronous function which makes an asynchronous request. The await keyword is used to pause the execution of the function until the Promise is resolved . Once the Promise is resolved, the response is assigned to the result variable, that then returned by the function.

When calling the function, since it returns a Promise, you need to use `.then()` to handle the result after the Promise is resolved.

```
async function bar() {
  var res = await foo();
  console.log(res);
}
```

Remember, you can only use await inside an async `function()`. If you’re not in an async function and want to use await, you will get a syntax error.